# How to handle nested lists and dictionaries in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a JSON file that includes a list of different data points. Each entry has the following structure, where the number of genres and reviews can vary a lot:

```
  {
    "title": "Golf Simulator",
    "genres": ["Sports", "Golf"],
    "score": 85,
    "critic_reviews": [
      { "review_critic": "XYZ", "review_score": 90 },
      { "review_critic": "ABC", "review_score": 90 },
      { "review_critic": "123", "review_score": 90 },
    ],
    "url": "http://example.com/golf-simulator"
  },
```

If I simply convert my JSON file to a python list and read it into a dataframe, the result looks something like this:

[image]

As you can see, the problem is that the nested elements are not handled in a very effective way. Now I am not sure myself what would be the best way to handle the data because as I mentioned, the amount of genres & reviews do vary.

Perhaps someone has worked with something similar and can share some tips on how to handle this.

Edit:

As I mentioned, I am not sure about what the best implementation would be - my guess is that one solution could be nested columns like this:

```
title            genres         critic_reviews
                 0       1      0                            
                                review_critic  review_score   
Golf Simulator   Sports  Golf   XYZ            90
```

Comment: Did you try `pd.read_json` ?

Comment: Just did, it has the same result

Comment: Not sure what your intentional output is, can you add that, if your variable is called `d` can you test `pd.json_normalize(d).stack().explode().to_frame('Values').T`

Comment: You may get somewhere using [Pandas MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html), both row- and column-wise.

Answer (score 2):

Not a Pandas solution, but still a solution I'd like to suggest: I would use an (in-memory) database instead, with related tables:

- game (title, score)
- genres (name)
- critics (name)
- game_genre (fk.game, fk.genre)  # allowing for multiple genres per game, and multiple games per genre
- reviews (fk.game, fk.critic, score)

(The "fk" indicators are foreign keys, and link the different tables.)

It will be a bit more cumbersome to apply operations to the tables (though not too much, provided you use proper SQL), but queries (e.g., list all games with an individual maximum review score of 65) are probably far easier.

Comment: That sounds like an idea, I will look into that. Thank you

Comment: Yes, I think this a a very valid solution. Of course, `pandas` can act as a SQL-like in-memory data struture, where each table is a different relation.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, though I do feel Pandas overextends itself at times, at the danger of making things more complicated than complete. I prefer simple 2D tables as much as possible with Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `flatten_json`:

```
from flatten_json import flatten
import pandas as pd

data= [ {
    "title": "Golf Simulator",
    "genres": ["Sports", "Individual", "Golf","Arcade"],
    "score": 85,
    "critic_reviews": [
      { "review_critic": "XYZ", "review_score": 90 },
      { "review_critic": "ABC", "review_score": 90 },
      { "review_critic": "123", "review_score": 90 },
    ],
    "url": "http://example.com/golf-simulator"
  }]

dict_flattened = (flatten(record, '.') for record in data)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_flattened)
df
```

Output should be :-

```
title           genres.0    genres.1    genres.2    genres.3    score critic_reviews.0.review_critic    critic_reviews.0.review_score   critic_reviews.1.review_critic  critic_reviews.1.review_score   critic_reviews.2.review_critic  critic_reviews.2.review_score   url
Golf Simulator  Sports      Individual  Golf        Arcade      85    XYZ                               90     ABC  90  123 90  http://example.com/golf-simulator
```

Comment: The amount of `genres.#` columns could become quite immense; similar to the critics columns.

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted based on your expected output. Or am I missing something?

Comment: BTW how many genres are you expecting for a single title? I dont think it will be immense.

Comment: The OP doesn't really know what they want: it says "I am not sure about what the best implementation would be - my guess is" right before the example.

Comment: Metacritic lists about 20 genres; that's already a considerable amount of columns. There are likely to be more critics in total.

Comment: Well, it seems logical to have a dataframe type that can be viewed at in a glance. 20 genres, plus, say, 40 critics, would lead to at least 20+2x40 columns: 100 columns seems a bit much to conveniently handle a dataframe.

Comment: If its an AI or Analytics use case then 100 columns is too few a number. Off course if you are going to manually analyze every column value it will be too much. I agree.